# Swift in iOS Cocoa Touch Static Library

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift, static, frameworks

I'm trying to use swift in a cocoa static library but the compiler is spitting back at me this:

```
Libtool /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-gmerfrjnryqwvmbjvschjjxdjyvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libSwiftFramework.a normal arm64
    cd /Users/USERNAME/Code/Examples/SwiftFramework
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk -L/Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-gmerfrjnryqwvmbjvschjjxdjyvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-gmerfrjnryqwvmbjvschjjxdjyvs/Build/Intermediates/SwiftFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftFramework.LinkFileList -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-gmerfrjnryqwvmbjvschjjxdjyvs/Build/Intermediates/SwiftFramework.build/Debug-iphoneos/SwiftFramework.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SwiftFramework.swiftmodule -o /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftFramework-gmerfrjnryqwvmbjvschjjxdjyvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libSwiftFramework.a

error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT] [-no_warning_for_no_symbols]
Usage: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]
```

This happens from creating a new project that is the Cocoa Touch Static Library and then adding an empty swift file to the target.

```
unknown option character `X' in: -Xlinker
```

Has anyone seen this when trying this in a static library?

Comment: Building the framework as a Cocoa Touch UI Framework seems to work so far. I will try that route.

Comment: how do I change it to be a Cocoa Touch UI Framework ? I've already added a couple hundreds of files to it before realizing this...

Comment: @LescaiIonel You can't make a Cocoa Touch framework for iOS using swift at the moment. I converted all my code to Obj-C and made it a cocoa touch framework

Comment: ^^^ This should say you can't create a cocoa touch framework with both swift and Obj-c at the moment. But to answer how to switch the target type? I am not sure you can go from one to the other without a large headache. I would start with a new target for the project and add the relevant files accordingly.

Comment: I ended writing that one swift class back to objective c.  So you CAN make a swift only library?

Comment: I believe you CAN yes. remember if you use cocoapods that this can be a major headache at a later time as most pods are obj-c